# How far should the answer go?

Tags: discussion

If there is question asked by a user who is not very familiar with mathematics, how far should the answer go? Is it better to have rigorous answers full of terminology and generalization of the result, or to explain in a not so mathematically rigorous but intuitive way which is easy for beginners (like me) to pick up?

Comment: That's why it is nice to have more than one answer, featuring various approaches.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Both. If you want to do one, do one. If you want to do the other, do the other. Answers are not only for the asker.

Comment: While I agree wholeheartedly, I'd like to add the following caveat: If you're giving a non-elementary answer to an elementary question, it's not a bad idea to say so. Otherwise the OP may think that the only way to address his/her question is through advanced methods (and thus may give up hope of understanding before other answers are posted).